# Choosing directory in aFileChooser

Tags: android, filechooser, android-afilechooser

I am using the aFileChooser library to let my user choose file. This library is good because it works with pre Kitkat and post Kitkat ( they changed how you can get the path for files/folders). In addition it shows internal and external.

The problem that I can only let the person choose files. I want the user to also be able to choose folders only  ( not files) and I can't seem to know how to do that or modify the code to do it.

Any help?

Comment: How do you want to differentiate between selecting a directory to change to, and selecting a directory to return as the result?

Comment: One possibility would be that every directory has an item (like a file) called "use directory" so it will use the path you are in.

Comment: Another option would be to have an OK button once you are in there

Comment: I think the simplest solution would be to set an `OnItemLongClickListener` on the ListView, add an `onDirSelected()` method to the `FileListFragment.Callbacks` interface, and call that in `onItemLongClick()` if the File `isDirectory()`. Other than that, it'd be a little more refactoring than I'd want to do.

Comment: The think is I dont think that code is always called. I tried stepping through the code and it seems the code is not called (maybe cause I have kitkat running) and the "localStorage" code is being called instead

Comment: Ah, it might be. I just glanced over the ListFragment code on github.